# Java Flight Recorder / Java Mission Control custom events for Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat8, java-mission-control, jfr

Are there Java Flight Recorder / Java Mission Control custom events for Tomcat?

If so, where are they documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None that I as a JMC developer know about, so likely no,
but it is of course possible.

Comment: Following your comment, could you please add how can I view JDBC logs using apache tomcat, because I know there's one named Weblogic Server in the Event Types, but for the case of a Tomcat server, nothing like such is visible in there... I have been hunting this down for over a week now and no fruitful attempts so far.